# external range in sumif formula in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

in a google spreadsheet I want to use the formula [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en);
the syntax of function is SUMIF(A1:A10,"Paid",B1:B10)

as first parameter (and last) I want use a range of another google sheet;
I used the function [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) but the result is always #N/A

my code is:
sumif(importrange("xxhEwtMr2xxzRmiucxRgA5P119SEmsqL2R08gggt4Yyg", "list!$E:$E"),$S7,importrange("xxhEwtMr2xxzRmiucxRgA5P119SEmsqL2R08gggt4Yyg","list!$C:$C"))

where am I wrong?

ps.
the error pop-up report:
`Error
Argument must be a range.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an easier work around is to use the import range to a new sheet.
Then sumif it from that sheet. It will still dynamically update.

Comment: Yes, ok, is a solution. But I would try to avoid a new sheet. I don't like have a hidden sheet for this type of work around.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the third argument in the SUMIF must be a direct reference to the local worksheet.

You can either add an additional tab to import the data into, or try a different formula approach such as:

`=SUM(QUERY(importrange("xxhEwtMr2xxzRmiucxRgA5P119SEmsqL2R08gggt4Yyg", "list!$C:$E"),"select Col1 where Col3 = '"&$S7&"'",0))`

Comment: why do you think that is only the third argument that needs a direct reference to the local worksheet? also the first argument is a range.

Comment: through testing I've found that the search range and criterion can both be importranges, but there is no output unless the sum range is within the same spreadsheet.  Not sure why this is the case but the SUM(QUERY()) formula I've suggested above gets round the issue.